# How can I open for edit 10k perforce files using list of files as parameter?

Tags: perforce

I have 10k perforce files mentioned in my file.txt.
I need to open them using p4 edit command.
I expect some command like "**p4 edit ?????file.txt**". Can you help me to check these files out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the -x flag on p4. This is assuming a UNIX shell.

```
cat file.txt | p4 -x - edit
```

Comment: I should mention this works with any command that takes an argument. This is a somewhat pointless example, but here it is: 

p4 changes -m 100  | awk '{print $2}' | p4 -x - describe

Comment: I am in windows, but you navigated me to solution: "p4 -x file.txt edit". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have some copy of directories structure where you have changes, and now you need to add those files to a change list. Which is impossible to do without checking them out. Am I right?

If I needed to change that much amount of files, I would do like this:

- Copy all files I wanted to check in replacing read-only files (Wondows Explorer can do that)
- In P4V go to a directory you need to check out files in, and then call "Reconcile offline work".
- In appeared dialog choose all files.
- Get new changelist with changed files being checked out.

I used this solution a couple of times - it works for added, changed and deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below command to edit all files present in file.txt

> p4 -x file.txt edit